# magento 2 installation in cpanel error

Tags: magento2, error

> Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under
>   application root directory.

How to solve it?

When installing magento 2 in cpanel and my company server

Comment: do you want to install it manually ? in your cpanel ?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. The error message already tells you what to do. WIthout further information you won't get much more help than that: **How** did you install Magento?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the one given in the error, just run:

```
composer install
```

In your Magento 2 root directory.